# Can I still play Phantasy Star Universe without the servers on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, phantasy-star-universe

I'm thinking about buying it, but then I read [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasy_Star_Universe#Server_closure):

> Due to low population, the North American and PAL PC/PS2 servers of Phantasy Star Universe were shut down on March 31, 2010. […] The Xbox 360 servers shut down on September 7, 2012.

I'm quite sure I read that Phantasy Star Online could be played offline, but I am not sure about Universe, so I am wondering: Can I still play Phantasy Star Universe (and the expansion/DLC) on the 360 despite the servers being shut down?

Answer (score 1):

You will still be able to access the base game and all of the offline content that was originally released. When the expansion was released on the Xbox 360, the entirety of the content was only made available online. If I remember correctly, the PS2/PC versions of the game did have some of the content available offline but sadly not the 360 version.